# IE 11 drop-down upon opened behavior adjustable?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Have a plain vanilla drop-down list, the way it displays content upon opened in IE 11 is totally diff from older versions. Is it any way make IE 11 show as IE 8?

IE 11:
[image: ie11]

IE 8:
[image: ie8]

```
<html>
<H2>Test plain drop-down in IE 11 </H2>
<br/><br/>

<p>
First item is pre-selected : <select id="testIE11">
<option value=0 selected>item 0</option>
<option value=1>item 1</option>
<option value=2>item 2</option>
<option value=3>item 3</option>
<option value=4>item 4</option>
<option value=5>item 5</option>
<option value=6>item 6</option>
<option value=7>item 7</option>
<option value=8>item 8</option>
<option value=9>item 9</option>
<option value=10>item 10</option>
<option value=11>item 11</option>
<option value=12>item 12</option>
</select>
</p>

6th item is pre-selected : <select id="testIE11">
<option value=0>item 0</option>
<option value=1>item 1</option>
<option value=2>item 2</option>
<option value=3>item 3</option>
<option value=4>item 4</option>
<option value=5>item 5</option>
<option value=6  selected>item 6</option>
<option value=7>item 7</option>
<option value=8>item 8</option>
<option value=9>item 9</option>
<option value=10>item 10</option>
<option value=11>item 11</option>
<option value=12>item 12</option>
</select>

</html>
```

Comment: The short answer: Probably not

Comment: Depends by what you mean...? the screen shots shows the select elements expanded. Normally in all IE versions (in well formed markup) select elements do not display the list until they receive focus. In your mashup code their is no body or form tags, which would by default receive focus before the select elements. The offset of the list from the parent select and body boundaries is different between IE versions.

Comment: A possible workaround is to use an imput element with a required attribute and bound to a datalist.

Comment: Another workaround would be to use a jquery plugin or jquery.mobile which converts <select> lists to display in a <ul><li></li></ul> design pattern, with the list offset at the bottom of the a dummy select element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a screen shot from an experiment exploring named colors in an input element (type text and type color) bound to a datalist element.

[image: datalist dropdown]

The datalist element is recognized in IE9 emulation modes and higher. Webkit, Gecko and MS Edge display a custom dropdown for input type=color, IE11 doesn't.A use case would be say for an order form for a motor vehicle... T-Ford any color so long as its black(#000)